# How do I access an encrypted home folder from a dual-boot machine?

Tags: encryption, partitioning, dual-boot, windows

(This might not be an Ubuntu-specific question?)

When I installed 9.10, I opted to encrypt my home folder using ecryptfs, but then I discovered this locked me out of my ext3 partition when I tried to access it from Windows on my dual-boot machine (using some free ext2/3 driver that I got somewhere, not even sure which one).

Is there a way to mount an encrypted home folder in Windows?

Comment: Did you encrypt the actual /home partition using say dm-crypt/LUKS or did you have your user created with the actual home directory encrypted (say /home/jono/) with ecryptfs? In simpler terms, did you do the select the encryption during partitioning or during user handling?

Comment: I rephrased it a bit; yes, I used ecryptfs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like no Windows support for ecryptfs is planned: 
[Is there a windows port of this available or in the works?](https://answers.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+question/63520)

Comment: That's such a shame to hear!

Answer (score 5):

If you use something like [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) you can access your drives from both Windows and Linux as long as you know the password. If you formatted it as ext2/3 you will need a ext2/3 driver to access it from Windows.

Comment: I agree. If you've got a dual-or-more-boot environment, I'd use Truecrypt with a FAT32 partition.

Comment: I'd prefer `ntfs-3g` with an NTFS partiotion. Large files, but I'd rather have EXT4.