# Will I able to access ecryptfs -ed folders in another installed Ubuntu?

Tags: directory, home-directory, ecryptfs, boot-partition

I have a HDD with Linux Ubuntu partition but with no Linux only Win7. I found a solution how to access and save my ext2 Linux files in Windows. I downloaded DiskInternals Linux reader. It accesses my Home folder but encrypted with Private 'ecryptfs'. I don't really know what it is? I cannot see my files. My questions: If I save this home folder under Windows. Will I be able to mount and access it under a new installed Ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access an encrypted home folder from a dual-boot machine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/278/how-do-i-access-an-encrypted-home-folder-from-a-dual-boot-machine)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen That's about accessing it from Windows...

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess I mis-read the question. Why not simply access the data with a live desktop CD ? Why are we using windows here ?

Comment: When you say Ubuntu Live Cd. Is it when you boot Ubuntu and click "Try Ubuntu", because I tried that way but it says I don't have permission to access Home folder.

Answer (score 0):

With ecryptfs your files are not actually in `/home/janos` but in subdirectories under `/home/.ecryptfs/janos` (assuming your username is janos).

Make sure you safe anything in this subdirectory!
Those files are also visible under Windows (though the filenames are garbled because of the encryption).

Considering this detail the answer is positive: You will be able to use these files in a newly installed Ubuntu.

It might become necessary to adjust the userid and permissions after replaying the backup (as Windows cannot store those natively) but the encrypted content is not damaged by backing up the encrypted files in Windows. Also no files outside of the `/home/.ecryptfs` directory are vital to the encryption.

Just make sure you configure your newly installed Ubuntu for using encrypted homes and just to be sure see to it, that the user in the new installation uses the same password as in the previous one.